# Are the Akaviri like the Japanese people of the real world?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-series

I found out about the Akaviri, who live in a continent just east of Tamriel called Akavir. I heard they had something to do with the Blades, a group of warriors who used to fight dragons and protect the Emperor. When I looked up the continent, it had provinces with Japanese names such as Tang Mo. I also looked up the people themselves and they look like Japanese samurai. Are the Akavir really like the Japanses people or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While there isn't any official statement supporting this, [the Skyrim wiki](http://skyrim.gamepedia.com/Akaviri) states that Akaviri people resemble China and Japan.

On a personal note, I checked the names and pictures of Akaviri NPCs and they really do look/sound like Japanese people/places.

Also, the pictures of Tang Mos resemble [Japanese macaques](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japanese_macaque).

Comment: Pictures of [Tang Mo](http://i.imgur.com/cvroLSq.jpg) and [Japanese Macaques](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japanese_macaque#/media/File:Macaca_fuscata_fuscata1.jpg) can be found on the links. (The noses, eyes and hair look pretty close)

Comment: http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Lore:Akaviri this has a bit more information.

Comment: @Ids I saw that too, but this wiki specifically stated that they resemble  China and Japan.